# CookieAuthenticationOptions, ExpireTimeSpan does not work

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following code:

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            ExpireTimeSpan = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/LogOff")
        });
```

But login session active more than 1 minute. Also, LogoutPath is not called when time is expired. Why?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It does expire.

Make sure you do not have any background ajax activity as it extends the session (`SlidingExpiration` is true by default).

Also I had to manually delete the old cookie after I changed `ExpireTimeSpan` from [the default 14 days](https://github.com/yreynhout/katana-clone/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationOptions.cs#L24) to a smaller value.

Comment: Deleting the cookies is what did it.

Comment: @Adas Petrovas where did you find these defaults, please?

Comment: I found it in the Katana source code. See line 24: [CookieAuthenticationOptions.cs](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationOptions.cs)

Comment: Note that thought the cookie itself is set to session expiration (expires only on browser closure), the expiration information is in the protected ticket itself (inside the cookie), thus the ticket could expire if the ExpireTimeSpan has passed, though the cookie didn't expire.

Comment: @RonyK Could you elaborate on this please? When I view the cookie info in Chrome console, it always tells me `Expires: Session`, regardless of whatever value I set in `ExpireTimeSpan`. Basically I want the cookie to stick around and not expire on session.

Comment: Nevermind, I realised you have to also set `IsPersistent = true` when signing in: `context.OwinContext.Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true }, cookieIdentity);`.

Answer (score 10):

You must set **IsPersistent** to true otherwise you don't run code

```
    ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(Claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

                var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    IsPersistent = true

                };

                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), authProperties);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this here because it took me ages to find and this post comes up every time I searched for the problem, so hopefully this helps someone else

I was using .NET framework 4.8 and OWIN, so my sign in function call looked like:

```
public virtual Task SignInAsync(
    TUser user,
    bool isPersistent,
    bool rememberBrowser
)
```

see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/mt173757(v=vs.108)

I wasn't using the built in 2FA but was still setting `rememberBrowser = true`  and no matter what I did the `ExpireTimeSpan` was ignored and it used the default of +14 days.

Once I set `rememberBrowser = false` everything worked as expected

I hope this saves someone else the entire day of googling and randomly changing stuff this cost me!