# Why doesn't cookie ExpireTimeSpan setting work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-core-identity

I used:

```
services.AddAuthenticationCore().ConfigureApplicationCookie(o =>
{
    o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
    o.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

to set my authentication cookie `ExpireTimeSpan` in **Startup.cs** in ASP.NET Core MVC project.

I can see that the cookie expire-time has been set correctly in the web browser after login, but it auto logout after 30 minutes every time, even if I refresh the website every 10 seconds.

If I set the `ExpireTimeSpan` less than 30 minutes, it can timeout correctly, but expire-time cannot be refreshed.

Why is it 30 minutes? Where can I change the 30 minutes timeout setting? Or is it set in IIS?

Comment: You mean ASP.NET Core, right?

Comment: Are you calling before or after `IdentityRegistrar.Register(services);`?

Comment: Yes,it is Asp.net Core,and I calling before  IdentityRegistrar.Register(services);

Comment: wasn't the sliding expiration the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is it 30 minutes?

It's the default of ASP.NET Core Identity.

> Where can I change the 30 minutes timeout setting? Or is it set in IIS?

No. Call `ConfigureApplicationCookie` after [`IdentityRegistrar.Register`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/a8134370dc22a64dc99a7f6f758044c7189c135b/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Mvc/Startup/Startup.cs#L42):

```cs
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...

    IdentityRegistrar.Register(services);                  // No change
    AuthConfigurer.Configure(services, _appConfiguration); // No change

    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(o =>
    {
        o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
        o.SlidingExpiration = true;
    });

    // ...
}
```

> "If you define it before the `services.AddIdentity`, your custom values will be overwritten."
>
> https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1389#issuecomment-324257591

Comment: Use set options.ValidationInterval solve my problem，I think it maybe  didn't pass the validity-check of the cookie。

Comment: Sorry for asking here, but I have exactly the same problem in ASP.NET MVC Standard, I can decrease the expire time but I'm not able to increase it, Do you have any idea?

Comment: this was the only one that worked in identityserver4 +1

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I'm posting this here because it took me ages to find a solution and this post came up a lot in my searches, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74292208/1540766